# SetWindowsHookEx fails ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER

Tags: c++, hook, createprocess, setwindowshookex

I wanted to catch CBT notifications of a specific process main thread that I've just created with:

```
STARTUPINFO startupInformation;
PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation;
CreateProcess(strWantedEXEPath,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    FALSE,
    0,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    &startupInformation,
    &processInformation);
```

And then if the creation was successful I tried to register with:

```
SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, CBTProc, GetCurrentModule(), processInformation.dwThreadId);
```

Which fails with error code `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`.

Nevertheless, if I tried to register for all threads with:

```
SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, CBTProc, GetCurrentModule(), 0);
```

It will work and catch the notifications from the created process main thread, but I don't want to use this because it will also catch notifications from other processes (and inject the dll I think).
So any tips on this problem?

Comment: Do your program and the program started with `CreateProcess()` have the same bit-ness (32-bit vs 64-bit)?

Comment: GetCurrentModule() probably, whatever it does.  You need to pass the module handle of a DLL that can be injected into the target process.  And it needs to be compatible with the target process, a 64-bit process requires a DLL containing 64-bit code.  These kind of hooks are difficult.

Comment: I didn't think about that, nevertheless, they are of same bitness and the dll is injected with success when I register the hook for all threads on system since I can catch notifications from the specific thread I wanted.

GetCurrentModule() I used an implementation described in here http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/dll/tips/article.php/c3635/Tip-Detecting-a-HMODULEHINSTANCE-Handle-Within-the-Module-Youre-Running-In.htm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SetWindowsHookEx functioning returning NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49407028/setwindowshookex-functioning-returning-null)