# SetWindowsHookEx functioning returning NULL

Tags: c, windows, dll, dll-injection

I am working on DLL Injection but getting the error as
**failed to hook process: 87 The parameter is incorrect.**

The target process as well as the dll are both 64 bit.

The Injection code is:

```
BOOL HookInjection(TCHAR target[], TCHAR *dll_name)
{
    // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx
    // SetWindowsHookEx can be used to inject a DLL into another process. A 32 - bit DLL cannot be injected into a 64 - bit process, 
    // and a 64 - bit DLL cannot be injected into a 32 - bit process.If an application requires the use of hooks in other processes, 
    // it is required that a 32 - bit application call SetWindowsHookEx to inject a 32 - bit DLL into 32 - bit processes, 
    // and a 64 - bit application call SetWindowsHookEx to inject a 64 - bit DLL into 64 - bit processes.The 32 - bit and 64 - bit DLLs must have different names.

    DbgPrint((char*)"[ ] loading module in local process");
    auto hdll = LoadLibrary(dll_name);
    //Load module ->Loads the specified module into the address space of the calling process. The specified module may cause other modules to be loaded.

    DbgPrint((char*)"[+] loaded dll\n");

    typedef LRESULT(WINAPI * MyProc)(int code, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp); // export from calc_dll.dll

    //GetProcAdress -> // GetPROCEDUREAdress Retrieves the address of an exported function or variable from the specified dynamic-link library (DLL).
    HOOKPROC addr = (HOOKPROC)(GetProcAddress(hdll, "print_successful_injection"));
    //auto mp = MyProc(GetProcAddress(hdll, "StartW"));
    //If you know who uses StartW, hush, its a secret ;)
    DbgPrint((char*)"[] It worked");
    auto pStartupInfo = new STARTUPINFO();
    auto pProcessInfo = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();


    DbgPrint((char*)"[ ] creating process to hook");
    CreateProcess(target,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        FALSE,
        NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        pStartupInfo,
        pProcessInfo);
    if (!pProcessInfo)
    {
        DbgPrint((char*)"[-] pprocessInfo fucked up");
    }

    if (!pProcessInfo->hProcess)
    {
        DbgPrint((char*)"[-] failed to create process");
        return FALSE;
    }
    DbgPrint((char*)"[+] Created hook process\n");

    DbgPrint((char*)"[ ] creating process hook");
    auto hProc = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT,   // Installs a hook procedure that receives notifications useful to a CBT application
        addr,                                   // my proc symbol taken from the dll
        hdll,                               // dll containing my proc
        pProcessInfo->dwThreadId);          // dword to the thread (something something windows store) RTFM
    if (!hProc)
    {
        DbgPrint((char*)"[-] failed to hook process");
        //This is where the code fails ie hproc is NULL
        return FALSE;
    }
    DbgPrint((char*)"[+] hook injected");
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hProc);

    return TRUE;
}
```

The dll that will be injected is as follows:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<Windows.h>

LRESULT __stdcall print_successful_injection(int code, WPARAM w, LPARAM l)
{
    MessageBox(0, L"Successfully Injected!", L"Hello", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    return (CallNextHookEx(NULL, code, w, l));
}
```

The def file is as follows:

```
LIBRARY "dll_to_inject"
EXPORTS
print_successful_injection
```

the DbgFunction works as follows:

```
VOID DbgPrint(char *msg)
{

#ifdef DEBUG
DWORD eMsgLen, errNum = GetLastError();//dword is unsigned int
LPTSTR lpvSysMsg; // __Out__ LPTSTR lpBuffer , A pointer to a buffer that receives the null-terminated string that specifies the formatted message

if (msg)
    printf("%s: ", msg);

//FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER -> The function allocates a buffer large enough to hold the formatted message, and places a pointer to the allocated buffer at the address specified by lpBuffer.The lpBuffer parameter is a pointer to an LPTSTR
//FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM -> The function should search the system message-table resource(s) for the requested message
eMsgLen = FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,
    NULL, errNum, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
    (LPTSTR)&lpvSysMsg, 0, NULL);

//If the function succeeds, the return value is the number of TCHARs stored in the output buffer, excluding the terminating null character.
//If the function fails, the return value is zero.

if (eMsgLen > 0)
    _ftprintf(stderr, _T("%d %s\n"), errNum, lpvSysMsg);
else
    _ftprintf(stderr, _T("Error %d\n"), errNum);
if (lpvSysMsg != NULL)
    LocalFree(lpvSysMsg);
#endif
}
```

I'm pretty new to stackoverflow so I hope I tried to provide as much as details necessary.

Comment: Did you try calling GetLastError() to see why SetWindowsHookEx failed?

Comment: The DbgFunction does that. It returns 'failed to hook process: 87 The parameter is incorrect.'

Comment: Just checking, you've verified that addr and hdll are set correctly?  I don't see you checking the return values of LoadLibrary or GetProcAddress.  I wouldn't expect them to fail, but you should check those return values.

Answer (score 3):

`SetWindowsHookEx` fail if it called not for GUI thread. more exactly if `Win32Thread` field of `KTHREAD` is 0. you call `SetWindowsHookEx` too early - thread yet not GUI thread (not initialized gui subsystem). so you need wait for this, before call `SetWindowsHookEx`. not sure, are possible catch exactly moment (after thread call `NtGdiInit`), when already possible call `SetWindowsHookEx`, but simplest way call `WaitForInputIdle(pi.hProcess, INFINITE)` with handle of new created process and only after it return `WAIT_OBJECT_0` call  `SetWindowsHookExW`

also, as separate note - for what you allocate `STARTUPINFO` and `STARTUPINFO` from heap ? (and not free it late). simply declare it as local variables in function. also `STARTUPINFO` must be initialized, how minimum as`STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(si) }` ; also you not close process and thread handles

Comment: the problem still persists

Comment: @tejaskulkarni - if you correct write code - must not. faster of all you mistake somewhere. and simply run your code under debugger - step by step (this give enough time to child process to begin run) - still 87 ?